# Changing JSSOR Idle time dynamically

Tags: jssor

Changing idle time dynamically doesn't work for me.
I try (as user 'jssor' suggested in other threads):

```
<div u="slides" ...>
    <div idle="2000"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

or

```
<div u="slides" ...>
    <div data-idle="2000"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

in which I change value 2000 by JS anytime, but without luck even after some more slides gone.
I need see change at current or next slide
jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/d80o10kb/1/

Comment: I have the same problem.  I also tried both options to no avail. Tried defining the idle time by setting $Idle property and still no success (http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html).  My site is using version 18.0.  I'm not interested in updating as the slider is working fine except for this idle time which theoretically should be easy to configure.

Comment: Just found out that my version works by setting property $AutoPlayInterval instead of $Idle; the former deprecated in favor of the latter.  Perhaps the two methods above are for newer versions using $Idle?  What's your version? Please write here when you resolve this. I'll settle for non-dynamic method for now. thanks

Comment: I use latest jssor 20.0. Startup setting works fine with {$AutoPlayInterval: 2000,....}. I had problem with dynamic change after init. JSSOR support ignores this problem and doesn't offer source code of new jssor (old versions have source code available)